pyrogram Как передать в бота сообщение, полученное пользовательским клиентом
Пишу скрипт, который состоит из userbot и chatbot, мне нужно, чтобы когда userbot(он же пользователь) получает новое сообщение, оно передаётся в chatbot и тот пересылает его на другой акаунт
cleint=Client('client', api_id,api_hash)
bot=cleint=Client('bot', api_id,api_hash)

@client.on_message():
async def(client: Client, message: Message):
  global bot
  await bot.send_message(user_id, message.text)
  
 client.start()
 bot.start()

Пока придумал только такую реализацию но она не работает

И убедись, что сообщения вообще приходят:
cleint=Client('client', api_id,api_hash)
bot=cleint=Client('bot', api_id,api_hash)

@client.on_message():
async def(client: Client, message: Message):
  global bot
  await bot.send_message(user_id, message.text)
  

 bot.start()
 client.run()


Спасибо, очень помогли :)
